# Form submit or $http call on ng-blur of div : AngularJS

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to add ng-blur(onFocusOut event) on a div where div contains html input elements radio and checkbox. Because ng-model holding my value in array(sample) So I want to fire event when focus out from div not from every input element contains by div. On focus out of div I'll have $http service to save model at server.

```
<div ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="focusCtrl">
            <div ng-blur="sentHttp()" style="height:100px;width:100px;background-color:blue;">
               <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="sample[shrk]" />A
               <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-model="sample[shrk]" />b

        <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="sample[shrk]" />1
        <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="sample[shrk]" />2
        <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="sample[shrk]" />3

           </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

angular Controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('focusCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.sample= {};
    $scope.sentHttp = function() {
        console.log("I'm called!");
        };
}]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As someone said div doesn't fire the focus/blur event, but, using a simple trick, you can implement it...

The solution resides on the `tabindex` attribute...
https://www.barryvan.com.au/2009/01/onfocus-and-onblur-for-divs-in-fx/

It works when clicks outside the div, but not with the tab... you need to work more with this snippet...

```js
function TestCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.fields = {
    "firstname": "Giuseppe",
    "surname": "Mandato"
  };
  
  $scope.sendHttp = function() {
    console.log("fields", $scope.fields);
  };
}

angular
  .module('test', [])
  .controller("TestCtrl", ["$scope", TestCtrl])
;
```

```css
.test {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  background: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="test">
  <article ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    
    <div ng-blur="sendHttp($event)" tabindex="-1" class="test">
      <input type="text" ng-model="fields.firstname" />
      <input type="text" ng-model="fields.surname" />
    </div>
    
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe ng-blur internally implements `onfocusout` event and since div doesn't fire the `onfocusout`, `ng-blur` will not work in this case

You need to listen to `click` event on the body and check if the target was not the `div` and then perform something